# Negative connotation in unremitting

Tags: word-usage, connotation

I am a non-native speaker.

Think about a man who is sitting beside his wife in a hospital all along. Would `unremitting` be unsuitable to describe him?

> The whole night through, the man sat unremittingly beside her.

I am asking because I looked up the definition for `unremitting` and found that both `relentless` and `incessant` are strong synonyms which I thought possess a rather negative connotation of rigidity, stubbornness or annoyance.

Edit:
Note that I am not looking for alternatives or synonyms. I'm interested in a possible implication of something that may be disapproved of `unremitting`

Comment: I think you are looking for "*constantly*". or "*continually*".

Comment: @Josh61 thanks but I'm not looking for alternatives, I merely want to know whether or not `unremittingly` sounds like he is stubborn or not. (Or has another negative implication)

Comment: Acknowledging that you're not looking for alternatives, note that "ceaselessly" tends to express admiration whereas "incessant," as you've noted, suggests that you wish it would stop.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It does have a mildly negative connotation (rather like incessant).  This makes sense given the [definition of remit](http://www.merriam-webster.com/dictionary/remit): "exacting or inflicting (a debt or punishment)."

Answer (score 1):

I am assuming that the man's wife is gravely ill in which case he probably is *relentless* in his belief that she will survive. He probably is *incessant* the she will pull through and he may very well be *annoyed* with the doctor's prognosis. It seems very suitable to me. If *unremitting* is in reference to his attitude about his wife's future, and not directed at his wife, then perhaps the negativity is what is intended.